# How to delete(or replace) all characters between 2 selected characters. Sed. Bash

Tags: bash, unix, sed

Let we have a string: `./dfsgfd/dfs/as/ssss`.

I need to get this: `|-----ssss`

So I write a script with sed: sed -r -e `'s/.\//|--/;s/\//-/g;s/-[^\-]*-/--/g;'`

By this regexp `sed -r -e 's/.\//|--/;s/\//-/g;'` I got: `|--dfsgfd-dfs-as-ssss`
.

And now I need to delete all characters between - and -. How can I do this? This regexp doesn't do it well: `s/-[^\-]*-/--/g;`.

Thank you!

Comment: Your requirement is to get `|-----ssss` as output - Right ? Where we have 5 "-" followed by pipe symbol. Is there any criteria to print these five "-" ?

Comment: You really don't need `sed` for this... `echo "|-----${s##*/}"` where `$s` is your string...

Comment: Are you looking for something like this - 

`echo "./dfsgfd/dfs/as/ssss"|sed -r -e 's/.(.*)\//|-----/'`
 output  `|-----ssss`

Comment: Unless you can explain how `|-----` relates to `./dfsgfd/dfs/as/`, because it's not at all obvious, even from the `sed` attempts you've made, I'm going to suggest that `echo "|-----ssss"` might be an appropriate solution...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right:

- you want replace every `/` with `-`
- delete all between chars but -
- prepend it with `|-`

one of many possible solutions

```
str='./dfsgfd/dfs/as/ssss'
out="|-$( sed 's:[^/]::g;s:/:-:g' <<<"${str%/*}/" )${str##*/}"
echo "$out"
```

output

```
|-----ssss
```

from: `str='./a/b/c/d/e/f/g/i/jjj'`

```
|----------jjj
```